# multiple blob file insertion php

Tags: php, mysql, file, blob

i have a form where the user inputs his info and has the ability to insert more than 1 longblob file (either an image or another file such as pdf), the insertion isn't working yet, but i'm able to manually insert file in MySQL and retrieve it ( View / download ), the attachment is to be uploaded to an "Attachment" Table and into a column "attachment" in Customer table, here's a code snippet of what is achieved:

```
<?php function insertFile_db($myFile,$conn,$tablename,$id){
                $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
                $sql="INSERT INTO Attachments (tableName,CustomerId,Name,File,Size,Type) ";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {

                       $fileName=$myFile["name"][$i];                                        // Note : $myFile=$_FILES['Attachment']
                        $fileTmp_name=$myFile["tmp_name"][$i];
                        $fileType=$myFile["type"][$i];
                        $fileSize=$myFile["size"][$i];

       //$fileContent = addslashes(file_get_contents($myFile['images']['tmp_name']));
        $file=fopen($fileTmp_name,'r');           //'r' open for reading only, pts at the beginning of the file
        $fileContent=fread($file,$fileSize);
        fclose($file);
         $fileContent = addslashes($fileContent);

             if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
             $fileName = addslashes($fileName);

         if( $i==($fileCount-1) && $i==0 )
            $sql.="VALUES ('".$tablename."', ".$id.", '".$fileName."','$fileContent','".$fileSize."','".$fileType."')" ; 
         else if($i!=($fileCount-1) && $i==0)
            $sql.="VALUES ('".$tablename."', ".$id.", '".$fileName."','$fileContent','".$fileSize."','".$fileType."')," ;
         else if($i==($fileCount-1) && $i!=0 )
            $sql.="  ('".$tablename."', ".$id.", '".$fileName."','$fileContent','".$fileSize."','".$fileType."')" ;         
         else   
            $sql.="  ('".$tablename."', ".$id.", '".$fileName."','$fileContent','".$fileSize."','".$fileType."')," ; 

            }


    if(!$conn->query($sql))
        return True;

    return Flase;

} ?>
```

and i'm calling the function :

```
if(isset($_FILES['Attachment']) &&  !empty($_FILES['Attachment']['name'][0])){
     $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
         $error=insertFile_db($_FILES['Attachment'],$conn,CONTNAME,$last_id);
       if($error===True)
            {$conn->close();header("location:/skylite/".CONTNAME."/Create?error=Internal error");exit();}

}
```

Now i'm focusing on insertion in Attachment table, i'd appreciate some tips and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking for errors with mysqli_error(), the main problem was a "Date" field in my database that didn't have a default value, therefore the query wasn't working, posting this in case someone else had such a problem, this was one solution!